# Redirección header no funciona

Tags: php, html

En mi página web he implementado redirección automática y para ello, tengo un "script intermediario" que gestiona alertas que comentaré ahora con ejemplos.

El principal problema es que esta redirección funciona correctamente en modo local cuando realizo pruebas, pero a la hora de subir todos los scripts al servidor para hacerla pública, deja de funcionar. Les explico mi código y las pruebas que he realizado:

Primero, por ejemplo, cuando realizo una acción, en este caso, borrar un usuario, ejecuto la siguiente instrucción:

```
    header('Location: mostrarAlertas.php?codAlerta=1');
```

Esto, redirige la página al momento a mostrarAlertas.php con un código 1, para detectar qué mensaje incluir

En mostrarAlertas.php se incluye el siguiente código

```
switch($codigo){
                case 1:
                    echo "<h1>Usuario borrado correctamente</h1>";
                    echo "<p>Te redireccionamos a la página de inicio.</p>";
                    header("refresh:5; url=index.php");             
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ...
                    break;
                case ...
}
```

He probado a realizar el refresh en el primer php y eso funcionaba correcto, pero mi intención es concentrar todos estos mensajes en mostrarAlertas.php. Con esto, he sacado la pequeña conclusión de que lo que no funciona es "una doble redirección" aunque quizá esta hipótesis sea precipitada.

Comment: Te recomendaría que uses Ajax. Todo se gestionaría desde le mismo sitio, sin el lío que supondrían las redirecciones, las recargas de páginas y demás historias. Quizá sea el momento de modernizar tu código.

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta! Es para un proyecto de la universidad y aún no controlo todo bien. Sobre tu recomendacion de usar Ajax, lo he usado un poco para otros temas, y no veo claro ahora mismo como organizar la funcion o en que lugares la pondría para realizar la redirección automática con retardo que tengo planteada

Comment: El *quid* del asunto es que con Ajax la redirección quizá no sea necesaria, porque puedes actualizar el cliente mostrando nueva información... tampoco sé si en el proyecto te permiten Ajax o tengas que hacerlo obligatoriamente con redirecciones. En caso de necesitar un temporizador, éste pasaría también del lado del cliente, con funciones propias de Javascript. La cuestión es que Ajax te permite pensar tu página como un escritorio o algo así desde el cual puedes gestionar todo de forma interactiva, e interactuar con el servidor. Es todo más rápido y más elegante, evitando recargas de páginas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes usar `header()` después de haber generado alguna salida y tú tienes un par de `echo` previos. Probablemente obtengas un mensaje `Can't send header ... headers already sent ...`

Ya que estás usando una "página intermedia" entonces hazla de la forma correcta, creando un HTML completo e incluyendo la redirección con una etiqueta [meta refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh), así no dependes de que PHP tenga configurado un buffer de salida ni de que el navegador reconozca un encabezado no estándar.

Crea variables para título, mensaje y url a donde se va a redirigir, de acuerdo al código recibido por GET

```
<?php
$codigo = (isset($_GET['codAlerta'])) ? $_GET['codAlerta'] : 0;
switch($codigo){
                case 1:
                    $titulo = 'Usuario borrado correctamente';
                    $mensaje = 'Te redireccionamos a la página de inicio.';
                    $url = 'index.php';
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ...
                    break;
                case ...
                    ...
                    break;
                default:
                    // Cuando el código es cero o un valor no contemplado
                    $titulo = 'Acción no reconocida';
                    $mensaje = 'El valor recibido no se reconoce.';
                    $url = 'index.php';
                    break;
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $titulo; ?></title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=<?php echo $url; ?>">
</head>
<body>
    <h1><?php echo $titulo; ?></h1>
    <p><?php echo $mensaje; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Efectivamente, el error era el de headers already sent