# Cannot modify header information - Cuando envio mas de 2 emails con PHPMailer

Tags: php

Estoy intentado enviar distintos emails a usuarios de la aplicación, resulta que si envio más de 2 me da el error:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\app\PHPMailer\class.smtp.php:239) in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\app\actionAdmin\insert-offer.php on line 37

El error hace referencia a un header que tengo, pero lo que no entiendo es por que con 2 me funciona correctamente, me hace el header, y ya si son 3 ya no me lo hace el header, la aplicación hace su trabajo de enviar los correos correctamente, pero no me redirige.  No sé ya que hacer la verdad. Buenas  noches

```
  foreach( $email  as  $email ){

                 $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
                 $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
                 $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
                 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
                 $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                 $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
                 $mail->IsHTML(true);
                 $mail->Username = "corominesempleo@gmail.com";
                 $mail->Password = "corominesempleo20";
                 $mail->SetFrom($email['email']);
                 $mail->Subject = $titulo;
                 $mail->Body = $cuerpo;
                 $mail->AddAddress($email['email']);

                    if(!$mail->Send()) {
                    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                    } else {
                    echo "Message has been sent";
                    }
            }
```

```
            $carpeta = "../actionAdmin/files/";
            opendir($carpeta);
            $destino = $carpeta.$_FILES['imagen']['name'];
            copy($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'],$destino);

            $nombreImg = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];


    $administrador->agregarOferta($titulo,$empresa,$email,$sector,$localidad,$descripcion,$nombreImg,$destino);

    $administrador->getEmail('Oferta de Empleo nueva','Estos son los datos de la oferta');

    $_SESSION['insertado'] = 'insertado';
      header("Location: ../views/panel-admin.php");
              exit();
    }
```

Comment: primero corrige`$email  as  $email` ambas se llaman igual ,, segunda correcion no utilices el mismo objeto para enviar todos los emails porque enviara 3 correos a cada destinatario ya que es una instancia del primero. no esta todo el codigo que utilizas tampoco especifica las version de phpmailer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes usar `header()` después de haber enviado contenido al navegador y tienes un `echo` después de enviar cada mensaje.

> con 2 me funciona correctamente

Sí, porque en algunas configuraciones PHP tiene habilitado un buffer de salida, donde va almacenando contenido hasta que completa cierta cantidad de datos.

Cuando se llena el buffer, PHP envía la salida, incluyendo encabezados, ya sea text/plain o text/html, de forma que el navegador sepa qué es lo que va a mostrar.

> y ya si son 3 ya no me lo hace el header

En el paso anterior se llenó el buffer, se envió contenido (incluyendo encabezados) y es por eso que obtienes el mensaje de error.

¿Solución? Lee [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/359408/redirecci%c3%b3n-header-no-funciona/359475#359475) y trata de adaptarla a tus necesidades.