# ¿Como puedo solucionar los direccionamientos después de iniciar sesión en php?

Tags: php, login

Mi sistema funciona muy bien en local. El problema es que cuando lo subo a un hosting inicia sesion pero no redirecciona al inicion se queda en login, otra cosa curiosa es que si funciona en logout me redirecciona al inicio pero creo que no comprueba si existe sesion en otros indexes

```
    class ControlSesion
{

    public static function iniciar_sesion($id_usuario, $nombre_usuario)
    {

        if (version_compare(phpversion(), "5.4.0") != -1) {
            if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
                session_start();
            }
        } else {
            if (session_id() == '') {
                session_start();
            }
        }
        $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $id_usuario;
        $_SESSION['nombre_usuario'] = $nombre_usuario;
    }


    public static function cerrar_sesion()
    {
        if (version_compare(phpversion(), "5.4.0") != -1) {
            if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
                session_start();
            }
        } else {
            if (session_id() == '') {
                session_start();
            }
        }

        if (isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'])) {
            unset($_SESSION['id_usuario']);
        }

        if (isset($_SESSION['nombre_usuario'])) {
            unset($_SESSION['nombre_usuario']);
        }

        session_destroy();
    }

    public static function sesion_iniciada()
    {

        if (version_compare(phpversion(), "5.4.0") != -1) {
            if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
                session_start();
            }
        } else {
            if (session_id() == '') {
                session_start();
            }
        }


        if (isset($_SESSION['id_usuario']) && isset($_SESSION['nombre_usuario'])) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Aqui dejo la clase de redireccion:

```
        class Redireccion
{
    public static function redirigir($url)
    {
        header("Location:$url", true, 301);
        exit();
    }
    
}
```

Despues de todo esto no logro hacer que redireccione como lo hace en local no he dado con la causa, si se dan cuenta hago una verificación de la version de php para validar si debo usar session_status o session_id y no tiene que ver con la sesion es que simplemente despues de validar el codigo no redirecciona pero si me habilita la sesion

Comment: ¿Obtienes algún mensaje de error como `headers already sent` u otro?

Comment: Nada simplemente no inicia hice unas respuestas de comprobacion para detectar el fallo y por eso hice la pregunta,
puedes probar user : admin clave : admin
https://sistema-ventas777.000webhostapp.com/login

Comment: Por lo general los headers se utilizan antes de que se cargue el contenido, entonces en la línea `header("Location:$url", true, 301);` sí debería mostrar el error que menciona @Triby.

Comment: Lo único es que hago todo en la misma vista de login

Comment: Bueno, parece que tienes desactivados los errores. No funciona porque estás enviando contenido antes del encabezado. Lee esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/359408/redirecci%c3%b3n-header-no-funciona/359475#359475

Comment: Ese no es mi problema relamente es que no redirecciona porque me pone el login en blanco en lo que valida el usuario correctamente

Comment: Añado más detalles: Cuando valida y justo despues de supuestamente redireccionar se queda la pagina del login en blanco