# ¿Como puedo hacer para que cuando el cliente compre algo y pague por medio de PayPal, automáticamente se le descargue el archivo necesario?

Tags: javascript, html, paypal

he estado intentando ver si paypal me daba esa opción pero no la encuentro. Ya hize la pagina pero **quiero que cuando el cliente compre el producto, automáticamente se le descargue un archivo .zip en el cual está el producto** **Pero no se como hacer que cuando pague el precio del producto se le descargue.** Por que no puedo estar enviando a cada uno que compre.
La página está hecha en HTML, CSS, JS
Pero la tienda está solo con el maincard de PayPal y solo.
Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Deberias agregar tu codigo

Comment: De hecho es mejor que ademas de la opcion de descargar, envies un email para descargar el archivo por si el usuario quiere hacerlo despues junto con la informacion de su compra y clave secreta en caso se requiera.

Comment: [Esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/359408/redirecci%c3%b3n-header-no-funciona/359475#359475) te puede servir, solo asegúrate que la página a donde rediriges inicie la descarga.