# Hacer que formulario me devuelva pdf con un mensaje

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy haciendo un formulario con laravel 8 que al finalizar me descargue un pdf y me muestre un mensaje pero no puedo hacer que me muestre ambas cosas. O me descarga el pdf y no muestra nada o sólo muestra el msj y no descarga el pdf. Estos son mis controladores

Función que me genera el pdf

```
        protected function pdf($data){
        $pdf = \PDF::loadView('orden/ordenPDF', $data);
        return $pdf->download('archivo.pdf');
    }
```

Y acá lo llamo y trato de devolverlo con un mensaje

```
      $pdf=$this->pdf($data);
      $mensaje='La orden de compra se ha generado con éxito, se ha descargado un archivo PDF. Si desea 
      visualizar nuevamente la orden generada diríjase a la opción "Orden de compra -> Órdenes de 
     compra."';
        
      return $pdf; 
      return back()->with('success',$mensaje)
```

si solo uso `return $pdf` me descargar el pdf sin mensaje.
si solo uso `return back()->with('success',$mensaje)` me devuelve sólo el mensaje que está.

Probé con `return $pdf->with('success',$mensaje);` pero arroja el siguiente error: BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Http\Response::with does not exist.

Comment: laravel solo escucha el primer return, entonces si es por php el el como retornas, puedes utilizar  session()->flash('success',$mensaje) y despues hacer el return del pdf, sesion->flash() no necesita entrar en el return e impirmirlo asi  {!! Session::has('msg') ? Session::get("success") : '' !!}

Comment: me muestra el mensaje sólo cuando recargo la página manual ya que no hay ningún return back(). ¿Sabes cómo puedo solucionar eso? o hacer que pueda hacer algún return redirect o back y a la vez llamar a la función que me genera el pdf.

Comment: No puedes enviar HTML y descarga de archivo al mismo tiempo, revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/359408/redirecci%c3%b3n-header-no-funciona/359475#359475). Muestra el mensaje y usa una etiqueta `meta` para _"redirigir"_ a la descarga del archivo.

Comment: segun la documentacion puedes pasar un array
Route::get('/', function () {
    return [1, 2, 3];
});
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses

Comment: El route::get me devolvía una página en blanco. Al final deje el controlador con un `return $pdf` y al form de la view le pasé una función de js para actualizar la página al apretar el boton de "ingresar". Así solucioné el problema. Dejo el código:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final deje el controlador con un `return $pdf` y al form de la view le pasé una función de js para actualizar la página al apretar el boton de "ingresar". Así solucioné el problema.

VIEW:

```
       <script>
            function recargar(segs) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                   location.reload();
                }, parseFloat(segs) * 1000);
            }
       </script>

     <form action="{{ route('insertar')}}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" 
      id="formulario" onsubmit="recargar(1)">
      {!! Session::has('success')!!}
```

CONTROLADOR:

```
 $mensaje='La orden de compra se ha generado con éxito, se ha descargado un archivo PDF. Si desea visualizar nuevamente la orden generada diríjase a la opción "Orden de compra -> Órdenes de compra."';
  $pdf=$this->pdf($data);
  session()->flash('success',$mensaje);
         
  return $pdf;
```

Así me descarga el pdf y a la vez me actualiza la página a 1 segundo para mostrar el mensaje.